# libxml/xmlwriter.h not found in XCode4.6.1

Tags: xcode, linkedin-api, libxml2

I have integrated **LinkedIn** library for an iOS app [https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone/]which builds fine in Xcode 4.5.1 for iOS 6.0,..but when I use **Xcode 4.6.1** build fails saying **libxml/xmlwriter.h not found**
    I've **added libxml2.dylib** as library and **/usr/include/libxml2 to the header paths**.Still
the error persists.
    Can anyone please help me in this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2` to your `Header search path` in **Build Settings**?